# determining the language of a file from its filepath

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

In my VSCode extension I have a string filePath and need to know its associated language.

As the user can change the language associations in the configuration (`files.associations`) only checking for the known extensions does not work.

Is there a functionality in the VSCode API to do that? Or do I need to extract the information from the configuration using `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("files").get("associations")`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `workspace.openTextDocument` and `document.languageId`:

```
import { workspace } from 'vscode';

workspace.openTextDocument(pathToMyFile).then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.languageId)
})
```

This only opens the document from the disk, it will not show it in the editor.